# llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits) is getting detected instead of NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am using:

Ubuntu 18.04.1

Kernel version: 5.4.0-42-generic

NVIDIA 1660 TI (Lenovo Legion Y545)

I have secure boot disabled, I have reinstalled the nvidia drivers but no help to this problem.

Instead of the NVIDIA drivers showing up, I get *llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)*. I have tried everything and I can't seem to fix it.

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

Output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3ffc
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

***Edit***

What I did (steps):

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` to remove the existing one
2. Removed all the unnecessary PPA's so when I run `sudo apt update` it outputs:

   Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]

   Hit:2 http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

   Hit:3 http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease

   Hit:4 http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
   Fetched 88,7 kB in 1s (84,9 kB/s)

   ...
3. I run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` and do a reboot after that just like @Pilot6 suggested but I have no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited my qestion where I included some details.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Which Nvidia driver did you install?

Comment: I don't see that Nvidia drivers are installed. Run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`

Comment: I installed nvidia-435 proprietary driver. I did that through Software&Update center

Comment: Why did you install the `435`? It is obsolete.

Comment: @Pilot6 the same thing is happening after 440 installation.

Comment: Remove the PPA. All works for me from the official repos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110982/discussion-between-zrobot-and-pilot6).

Comment: @Pilot6 make a nice answer, you can better explain than I.

Comment: Yes @Pilot6, it would be great if there was a detailed answer for other users having similiar issues as mine. I'll make sure to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, then I make an answer. It turns out the nivida-packages (440) was not compatible wiith the kernel from Paket linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge (5.4:XXx) and blocks dkms itself.  Reverting to linux-generic (4.15.xxx) and purging (linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge) and his dependencies and reinstalling package nvidia-dkms-440 did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Secure Boot and installing nvidia-driver-XXX worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will be useful to anyone. I installed ubuntu 22.04 but the Graphics in Settings > About was showing as llvmpipe.

To resolve the issue, I performed the following steps.

1] I first disabled the `secure boot` option in the bios.

2] I added the graphics ppa for the Jammy Jellyfish (i.e. 22.04) and reinstalled the nvidia drivers : `sudo apt reinstall nvidia-driver-510` . Now everything is fine.

Comment: +1, Sounds useful, as the with latest update my VGA and my keyboard stopped working... How did you disable `secure boot`?

Comment: In the bios setting when the laptop boots up, press F2 to get into bios settings.